# Having troubles with Drupal.attachBehavior

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I am implementing some javascript that dynamically adds some html to the dom.  in this html I have some links that utilize the new ajax api in D7.  The problem I am running into is that Drupal.attachBehavior does not seem to be re-attaching itself to the newly added links.

```
var markup = '&lt;a class="use-ajax" href="/ajax/citation/highlight"&gt;Highlight&lt;/a&gt;';
$('ul.selection-toolbar').remove();
Drupal.detachBehaviors();
$(this).prepend(markup);                
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the `window` object. You do not want to prepend markup to the `window` object, because it does not do anything useful.

Comment: this is actually inside of a function.  $(this) is a <p> object in this scenario.

Comment: Then you should say so in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Drupal.attachBehaviors(document);` instead of `Drupal.attachBehaviors();`.

I made this change in my module and everything is working fine now.